# Why can't I receive an RTP video stream produced by GStreamer's appsrc?

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtp, gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch

I'm trying to use the GStreamer's `appsrc` element with `rtpbin` and `udpsink` to create an RTP sender using the VP8 codec (`vp8enc`).

This program creates a fake video stream by switching black and white frames every 100 milliseconds. You can see the video by uncommenting the macro `USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK`.

When I run the receiver, I only get the first frame. It doesn't blink. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using libgstreamer 1.20.3 from Ubuntu 22.04.

```c
// broadcaster.c
//
// Compile with:
// c99 -Wall -O3 -std=c99  `pkg-config gstreamer-1.0 --cflags --libs-only-l` -O0 -g -c broadcaster.c -o broadcaster

#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//#define USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
#define FRAME_WIDTH 320
#define FRAME_HEIGHT 240
#define FRAME_SIZE (FRAME_WIDTH * FRAME_HEIGHT)
#define FRAME_RATE_INTERVAL_MS 100
#define VIDEO_PT 101
#define VIDEO_SSRC 2222
#define VIDEO_TRANSPORT_HOST "localhost"
#define VIDEO_TRANSPORT_PORT 1234

typedef struct {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstElement *video_appsrc;
  GstElement *videoconvert;
#ifdef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
  GstElement *autovideosink;
#else
  GstElement *rtpbin;
  GstElement *vp8enc;
  GstElement *rtpvp8pay;
  GstElement *udpsink;  
#endif
  gboolean need_video_data;
  gboolean playing;
  gboolean use_black_buffer;
} CustomData;

static void need_video_data_callback(
  GstElement *appsrc,
  guint length,
  CustomData *data
);

static void enough_video_data_callback(
  GstElement *appsrc,
  CustomData *data
);

#ifndef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
static void pad_added_handler(
  GstElement *src,
  GstPad *new_pad,
  CustomData *data
);
#endif

static void* thread_proc(
  void *p_data
);

static int msleep(
  long msec
);

static gboolean terminate = FALSE;

static uint16_t black_buffer[FRAME_SIZE];
static uint16_t white_buffer[FRAME_SIZE];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CustomData data;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  pthread_t thread;
#ifndef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
  GstPad *rtpvp8pay_src_pad, *rtpbin_send_rtp_sink_0_pad;
#endif

  for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_SIZE; ++i) { 
    black_buffer[i] = 0;
    white_buffer[i] = 0xFFFF;
  }

  gst_init(&argc, &argv);

  data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("broadcaster-pipeline");

  data.video_appsrc = gst_element_factory_make(
    "appsrc",
    "video_appsrc"
  );

  data.videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make(
    "videoconvert",
    "videoconvert"
  );

#ifdef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
  data.autovideosink = gst_element_factory_make(
    "autovideosink",
    "autovideosink"
  );
#else
  data.rtpbin = gst_element_factory_make(
    "rtpbin",
    "rtpbin"
  );

  data.vp8enc = gst_element_factory_make(
    "vp8enc",
    "vp8enc"
  );

  data.rtpvp8pay = gst_element_factory_make(
    "rtpvp8pay",
    "rtpvp8pay"
  );

  data.udpsink = gst_element_factory_make(
    "udpsink",
    "udpsink"
  );
#endif

  data.need_video_data = FALSE;
  data.playing = FALSE;
  data.use_black_buffer = FALSE;

  if (
    !data.pipeline ||
    !data.video_appsrc ||
    !data.videoconvert ||
#ifdef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
    !data.autovideosink
#else
    !data.rtpbin ||
    !data.vp8enc ||
    !data.rtpvp8pay ||
    !data.udpsink
#endif
  ) {
    g_error("Error: Not all gstreamer elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  gst_bin_add_many(
    GST_BIN(data.pipeline),
    data.video_appsrc,
    data.videoconvert,
#ifdef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
    data.autovideosink,
#else
    data.rtpbin,
    data.vp8enc,
    data.rtpvp8pay,
    data.udpsink,
#endif
    NULL
  );

  if (
    !gst_element_link_many(
      data.video_appsrc,
      data.videoconvert,
#ifdef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
      data.autovideosink,
#else
      data.vp8enc,
      data.rtpvp8pay,
#endif
      NULL
    )
  ) {
    g_printerr("Error: Not all video elements could be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  g_object_set(
    data.video_appsrc,
    "is-live", TRUE,
    "stream-type", 0,
    "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
    NULL
  );

#ifndef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
  g_object_set(
    data.vp8enc,
    "target-bitrate", 1000000,
    "deadline", 1,
    "cpu-used", 4,
    NULL
  );

  g_object_set(
    data.rtpvp8pay,
    "pt", VIDEO_PT,
    "ssrc", VIDEO_SSRC,
    "picture-id-mode", 2,
    NULL
  );

  g_object_set(
    data.udpsink,
    "host", VIDEO_TRANSPORT_HOST,
    "port", VIDEO_TRANSPORT_PORT,
    NULL
  );  
#endif

  g_signal_connect(
    data.video_appsrc, 
    "need-data",
    G_CALLBACK(need_video_data_callback), 
    &data
  );

  g_signal_connect(
    data.video_appsrc, 
    "enough-data",
    G_CALLBACK(enough_video_data_callback), 
    &data
  );

#ifndef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
  g_signal_connect(
    data.rtpbin,
    "pad-added",
    G_CALLBACK(pad_added_handler),
    &data
  );

  rtpvp8pay_src_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(
    data.rtpvp8pay,
    "src"
  );

  rtpbin_send_rtp_sink_0_pad = gst_element_request_pad_simple(
    data.rtpbin,
    "send_rtp_sink_%u"
  );

  if (
    gst_pad_link(
      rtpvp8pay_src_pad, 
      rtpbin_send_rtp_sink_0_pad
    ) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK
  ) {
    g_printerr("Error: rtpvp8pay could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
    return -1; 
  }  
#endif

  if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_proc, &data)) {
    g_printerr("Could not create thread.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  bus = gst_element_get_bus(data.pipeline);
  do {
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(
      bus,
      GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      (GstMessageType)(
        GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED |
        GST_MESSAGE_ERROR |
        GST_MESSAGE_EOS
      )
    );

    if (msg != NULL) {
      GError *err;
      gchar *debug_info;

      switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
          gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
          g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n", 
            GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src), err->message);
          g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n", 
            debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
          g_clear_error(&err);
          g_free(debug_info);
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
          g_print("End-Of-Stream (EOS) reached.\n");
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
          if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC(msg) == GST_OBJECT(data.pipeline)) {
            GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
            gst_message_parse_state_changed(
              msg, 
              &old_state, 
              &new_state, 
              &pending_state
            );
            g_print(
              "Pipeline state changed from %s to %s: \n",
              gst_element_state_get_name(old_state),
              gst_element_state_get_name(new_state)
            );
            if (
              g_str_equal(
                gst_element_state_get_name(new_state),
                "PLAYING"
              )
            ) {
              GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE(
                GST_BIN(data.pipeline),
                GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL,
                "pipeline"
              );
            }
          }
          break;
        default:
          g_printerr("Unexpected message received.\n");
          break;
      }
      gst_message_unref(msg);
    }
  } while (!terminate);

  gst_object_unref(bus);
  gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
  g_print("Goodbye.\n");

  return 0;
}

static void need_video_data_callback(
  GstElement *appsrc,
  guint length,
  CustomData *data
) {

  g_print(
    "Video data is needed on '%s':\n",
    GST_ELEMENT_NAME(appsrc)
  );

  data->need_video_data = TRUE;
}

static void enough_video_data_callback(
  GstElement *appsrc,
  CustomData *data
) {

  g_print(
    "Video data is enough on '%s':\n",
    GST_ELEMENT_NAME(appsrc)
  );

  data->need_video_data = FALSE;
}

#ifndef USE_AUTOVIDEOSINK
static void pad_added_handler(
  GstElement *src,
  GstPad *new_pad,
  CustomData *data
) {
  GstPad *sink_pad = NULL;

  g_print(
    "Received new pad '%s'.'%s':\n",
    GST_ELEMENT_NAME(src),
    GST_PAD_NAME(new_pad)
  );

  if (src != data->rtpbin) {
    return;
  }

  if (g_str_equal(GST_PAD_NAME(new_pad), "send_rtp_src_0")) {
    sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(
      data->udpsink,
      "sink"
    );
  }

  if (
    sink_pad &&
    gst_pad_link(
      new_pad,
      sink_pad
    ) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK
  ) {
    g_printerr(
      "Error: %s.%s could not be linked to %s.\n",
      GST_ELEMENT_NAME(src),
      GST_PAD_NAME(new_pad),
      GST_PAD_NAME(sink_pad)
    );
  }

  if (sink_pad) {
    gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
  }      
}
#endif

static void* thread_proc(
  void *p_data
) {
  CustomData *data = (CustomData *)p_data;
  GstCaps *video_caps = NULL;

  g_print("Generating frames...\n");

  while (!terminate) {
    if (!video_caps) {
      video_caps = gst_caps_new_simple(
        "video/x-raw",
        "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB16",
        "width", G_TYPE_INT, FRAME_WIDTH,
        "height", G_TYPE_INT, FRAME_HEIGHT,
        NULL
      );

      g_object_set(
        data->video_appsrc,
        "caps", video_caps,
        NULL
      );      
    }

    if (video_caps && !data->playing) {
      GstStateChangeReturn ret;

      ret = gst_element_set_state(
        data->pipeline,
        GST_STATE_PLAYING
      );

      if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        terminate = TRUE;
        continue;
      }
      else {
        data->playing = TRUE;
        g_print("Playing the pipeline.\n");
      }
    }

    if (data->playing && data->need_video_data) {
      GstFlowReturn ret;
      guint size = FRAME_SIZE * 2;
      GstBuffer *buffer = gst_buffer_new_memdup(
        data->use_black_buffer ? black_buffer : white_buffer,
        size
      );
      g_signal_emit_by_name(
        data->video_appsrc,
        "push-buffer",
        buffer,
        &ret
      );
      gst_buffer_unref(buffer);

      data->use_black_buffer = !data->use_black_buffer;

      if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
        terminate = TRUE;
      }   
    }

    msleep(FRAME_RATE_INTERVAL_MS);
  }

  return NULL;
}

static int msleep(
  long msec
) {
  struct timespec ts;
  int res;

  if (msec < 0) {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
  }

  ts.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
  ts.tv_nsec = (msec % 1000) * 1000000;

  do {
    res = nanosleep(&ts, &ts);
  } while (res && errno == EINTR);

  return res;
}
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# receiver.sh

HOST=localhost
VIDEO_RTP_PORT=1234

VIDEO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)VP8"
VIDEO_DEC="rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec"
VIDEO_SINK="videoconvert ! autovideosink"

gst-launch-1.0 \
  rtpbin name=rtpbin \
  udpsrc caps=$VIDEO_CAPS address=$HOST port=$VIDEO_RTP_PORT \
  ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin. \
  ! $VIDEO_DEC \
  ! $VIDEO_SINK
```

Answer (score 1):

I have [asked](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2022-August/080275.html) in the [gstreamer-devel](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/lists/) mailing list, and it turns out [my buffers are missing timestamps](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2022-August/080279.html).

So I fixed the RTP sender by setting the `do-timestamp` property `TRUE` for the `appsrc`.

```c
  g_object_set(
    data.video_appsrc,
    "is-live", TRUE,
    "stream-type", 0,
    "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
    "do-timestamp", TRUE,
    NULL
  );
```